# Failed to include a python package (nltk) with Hadoop streaming job

Tags: python, hadoop, nltk, hadoop-streaming

I was following several of the posts to include nltk with hadoop streaming jobs. such as [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811549/how-can-i-include-a-python-package-with-hadoop-streaming-job), and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978467/reading-file-in-hadoop-streaming).

My mapper code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
trainingMapper1_test.py
'''


import sys
import zipimport


importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
nltk = importer.load_module('nltk')
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer


def getToken(input):
    tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
    allTokens = tokenizer.tokenize(input)
    return  allTokens

def read_input(file):
    for line in file:
        yield getToken(line)

def main(separator='\t'):
    data = read_input(sys.stdin)
    for tokenlist in data:
        for token in tokenlist:
            print ('%s%s%d' % (token, separator, 1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Basically I just tokenize the line, and then print token by token. **The script is fine when I test using the following command:**

```
python trainingMapper1_test.py < input.txt
```

However, when I run the hadoop with:

```
hadoop  jar $JARFILE  \
-D mapreduce.job.reduces=0 \
-input input_dir \
-output justatest \
-file nltk.mod \
-file trainingMapper1_test.py \
-mapper trainingMapper1_test.py
```

where the input_dir just contain one file, that is input.txt, I got exceptions:

> 18/04/09 01:03:31 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1523248713710_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>   Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:325)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:538)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:177)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:171)

I tested, it is the import failed from the line:

```
importer = zipimport.zipimporter('nltk.mod')
```

But I do not know how to fix this, it seems that `nltk.mod` is not sending to the workers or the workers cannot load it. Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Acutally, it is the line nltk = importer.load_module('nltk') which caused the exception. But Still I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?I am facing similar issue